# Need help running multiple countdown timers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have multiple countdown timers on a page, but running into a few issues where one of the countdown timers doesn't load. I tried to change the variables, but still nothing. Please help D:

```
<!-- Countdown Timer 1 -->


<p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
dateFuture = new Date(2014,11,8,9,0,0);

function GetCount(){

        dateNow = new Date();                                                                      
        amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
        delete dateNow;


        if(amount < 0){
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML="This pre-order has ended";
        }

        else{
                days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

                amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);

                days=Math.floor(amount/86400);
                amount=amount%86400;

                hours=Math.floor(amount/3600);
                amount=amount%3600;

                mins=Math.floor(amount/60);
                amount=amount%60;

                secs=Math.floor(amount);

                if(days != 0){out += days +" day"+((days!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                if(days != 0 || hours != 0){out += hours +" hour"+((hours!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                if(days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0){out += mins +" minute"+((mins!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                out += secs +" seconds" + " left to order";
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;

                setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
        }
}

window.onload=function(){GetCount();}
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div id="countbox" style="background-color: #b20a14; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px; color: #fff; font-size: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>



<!-- Countdown timer 2 -->




<p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
dateFuture2 = new Date2(2014,11,9,9,0,0);

function GetCount2(){

        dateNow2 = new Date2();                                                                      
        amount2 = dateFuture2.getTime() - dateNow2.getTime();
        delete dateNow2;


        if(amount2 < 0){
                document.getElementById('countbox2').innerHTML="This pre-order has ended";
        }

        else{
                days2=0;hours2=0;mins2=0;secs2=0;out2="";

                amount2 = Math.floor(amount2/1000);

                days2=Math.floor(amount2/86400);
                amount2=amount2%86400;

                hours2=Math.floor(amount2/3600);
                amount2=amount2%3600;

                mins2=Math.floor(amount2/60);
                amount2=amount2%60;

                secs2=Math.floor(amount2);

                if(days2 != 0){out2 += days2 +" day"+((days2!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                if(days2 != 0 || hours2 != 0){out2 += hours2 +" hour"+((hours2!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                if(days2 != 0 || hours2 != 0 || mins2 != 0){out2 += mins2 +" minute"+((mins2!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                out2 += secs2 +" seconds" + " left to order";
                document.getElementById('countbox2').innerHTML=out2;

                setTimeout("GetCount2()", 1000);
        }
}

window.onload=function(){GetCount2();}
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div id="countbox2" style="background-color: #b20a14; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px; color: #fff; font-size: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: `new Date2()`, did you ever define a prototype / class for Date2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from re-usable.

I've made a few changes so that you will be able to use the same function.

The important thing to look at here is that we're passing a date into the function rather than it looking at the global namespace. Also, the timeout function has to be called anonymously so that we can pass in the date parameter repeatedly.

I added a second parameter to the function that allows you to choose which element you want the countdown to appear in by ID.

Finally (and probably most importantly) the variables in the function have been prefixed with `var`. Why? Because if you have the same variable name inside and outside of the function - then it can cause problems with other code. We use `var` to tell our function, "Only work in here, please."

Now, you can create as many countdown clocks as you like. But do try to look at the changes and see how this can improve your coding.

```js
date1 = new Date(2014, 11, 8, 9, 0, 0);
date2 = new Date(2014, 12, 8, 9, 0, 0);
GetCount(date1, 'countbox');
GetCount(date2, 'countbox2');

function GetCount(dateFuture, targetID) {
  var dateNow = new Date();
  var amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
  delete dateNow;

  if (amount < 0) {
    document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML = "This pre-order has ended";
  } else {
    var days = 0,
      hours = 0,
      mins = 0,
      secs = 0,
      out = "";

    amount = Math.floor(amount / 1000);

    days = Math.floor(amount / 86400);
    amount = amount % 86400;

    hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
    amount = amount % 3600;

    mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
    amount = amount % 60;

    secs = Math.floor(amount);

    if (days != 0) {
      out += days + " day" + ((days != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    if (days != 0 || hours != 0) {
      out += hours + " hour" + ((hours != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    if (days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0) {
      out += mins + " minute" + ((mins != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    out += secs + " seconds" + " left to order";
    document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML = out;

    setTimeout(function() {
      GetCount(dateFuture, targetID);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
#countbox {
  background-color: #b20a14;
}
#countbox2 {
  background-color: #006;
}
```

```html
<div id="countbox" style="">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="countbox2" style=";">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems which are causing this to not run

First of all on lines 58 and 62 you have `Date2` - this should be `new Date()`

Secondly you can only have one function assigned to window.onload. You should use the more modern equavalent

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() { GetCount1(); }, false);
// or without the extra wrapping function 
document.addEventListener("load", GetCount1, false);
```

You could improve the code by noticing that GetCount1 and GetCount2 are pretty much exactly the same and creating a more function which will create the timer for you. This can replace **all** of the scripts that you have in your code sample.

```
function getCounter(endingDate, element) {
  return (function counter() {
    var dateNow = new Date(),
      amount = endingDate.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();

    if (amount < 0) {
      element.innerHTML="This pre-order has ended";
    } else {
      var days = 0,
        hours = 0,
        mins = 0,
        secs = 0,
        out = 0;

      amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);

      days=Math.floor(amount/86400);
      amount=amount%86400;

      hours=Math.floor(amount/3600);
      amount=amount%3600;

      mins=Math.floor(amount/60);
      amount=amount%60;

      secs=Math.floor(amount);

      if(days != 0){out += days +" day"+((days!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
      if(days != 0 || hours != 0){out += hours +" hour"+((hours!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
      if(days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0){out += mins +" minute"+((mins!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
      out += secs +" seconds" + " left to order";
      element.innerHTML=out;
    }
    setTimeout(counter, 1000);
  })();
}

// you can create a new timer with the getCounter function - e.g.
// getCounter (new Date(2014,11,8,9,0,0), document.getElementById("element_id"))

document.addEventListener("load", getCounter(new Date(2014,11,8,9,0,0), document.getElementById("countbox")), false);

document.addEventListener("load", getCounter(new Date(2014,11,9,9,0,0), document.getElementById("countbox2")), false);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're re-defining `window.onload`, only the last assignment will be executed, i.e. assigning `function() { GetCount2(); }` to it replaces the prior `function() { GetCount(); }`.

Instead, use either

```
window.onload = function() { GetCount(); GetCount2(); }
```

Or

```
document.addEventListener("load", GetCount, false);
// ... more code
document.addEventListener("load", GetCount2, false);
```

Also, as iblamefish and LcLk pointed, `new Date2` should most likely be `new Date()`

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote? What's wrong with this answer? :S